# Best library to implement jsonrpc 2.0 in java with bidirectional support

Tags: java, json-rpc, jsonrpc4j

I am in search of a library to implement jsonrpc 2.0 in java with bidirecional support. I have found these two ([JJsonRpc](https://github.com/nbarraille/JJsonRpc), [jsonrpc4j](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j)) some recommendation of which one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to write my own integration to the api json rpc using

**OKHttp** for HTTP connections and **Jackson Core** for fast JSON serialisation / deserialisation

Implementation Code:

https://github.com/AraguaneyBits/bitcoinrpc4java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/araguaneybits/crypto/bitcoinrpc/methods/BtcRpcGateway.java